# Gnuplot forced close, plotting data x in decimal y in integer

Tags: gnuplot

I want to plot data in gnuplot uisng this code

```
set xlabel "Sudut"
set ylabel "Intensitas warna"
set title "Grafik intensitas terhadap sudut"
set xrange [-1:1]
plot "data.dat" with lines
```

the data is 3023 for x (from negative to positive) and 3023 for x in integer, for example i put it a little here. but not showing anything (force close), can anyone help me?

```
-0,97773655 32
-0,977449456 30
-0,977162117 31
-0,976874533 26
-0,976586704 25
-0,97629863 32
-0,97601031 34
.
.
.
0,910961491 51
0,911306538 55
0,911651279 66
0,911995712 70
0,91233984 80
0,912683662 81
```

Comment: data x= -0,9xxxx  .  data y= 0-255

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explicitly set the locale as Gnuplot assumes dots as the decimal separator, e.g.:

```
set locale 'YOUR_LOCALE'
set decimalsign locale 'YOUR_LOCALE'
```

Where you replace YOUR_LOCALE with the relevant locale. On GNU/Linux you can see the available locales with:

```
locale -a
```

Comment: when i change to dots, it still forced close. not showing any graph

Comment: @luthfiharitsah: please add what you have tried (and it's results) to your original question